# 2022 年コミュニティモデレーター選挙

Tags: 討議, モデレーション, 選挙

2022 年度コミュニティモデレーター選挙が実施されます！

選挙は 3 つの段階で実施されます:

1. 立候補
2. 予備選
3. 選挙

候補者人数にもよりますが、通常の選挙期間は 2 〜 3 週間ほどです。

詳細は公式の選挙ページをご覧ください。

https://ja.stackoverflow.com/election

Stack Exchange 全サイトで使用されるタイムゾーンは UTC です。選挙ページに表示されている日時も UTC 時間であるため、立候補や投票をなさる際にはどうぞご注意くださいませ！日本時間 JST は UTC のプラス 9 時間（ UTC + 9 ）です。

どうぞご参加ください！

選挙過程やモデレーター候補についてはメタで遠慮なく質問してください。[選挙](/questions/tagged/%e9%81%b8%e6%8c%99)タグをどうぞお忘れなく。