# 2022 モデレーター選挙に向けて：事前興味度調査

Tags: 討議, モデレーション, 選挙

スタック・オーバーフローはベータを卒業し、そして 2022 年 3 月に初めてのモデレーター選挙を[行いました](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3708/19110)。その際は充分な数の立候補者が集まらず選挙の手順の途中で[中止となりました](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3715/19110)が、引き続きコミュニティのモデレーターを決めるための活動は続いており、次の選挙を開く準備が進められています。

モデレーターはコミュニティの[「例外処理機」](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/site-moderators)です。通常の投票やコメントなどのモデレーションでは解決できないようなことを解決するための役割を担っています。ベータを卒業した今、Stack Exchange 社からの推薦で決まった[暫定モデレーター](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2692/19110)ではなく、コミュニティの手によって正式なモデレーターを決めることは、今後もサイトをコミュニティ全体でモデレーションしていく上で重要な要素になるでしょう。

そこでこの投稿では、モデレーター選挙への立候補にご興味ある方がどのくらいいらっしゃるのかを調査したいです。事前に立候補者数をある程度把握しておくことで、選挙の手順が途中で止まってしまうことをなるべく避けたいと考えています。

もし次のモデレーター選挙が開催されたら立候補したいと考えていらっしゃる方は、そのことを回答としてこの質問に投稿いただけないでしょうか。特に内容は必要なく、ただ興味があることを示していただければ充分です。

3 人のモデレーターを選ぶためには、少なくとも 4 人の立候補が必要です。最終的に何人のモデレーターが選ばれることにするのかを考える参考にするために、遠慮なくご投稿いただけると幸いです。

なお、ここでの回答は正式な立候補ではなく、あくまで規模感をはかるための参考になります。特に凝った内容を書く必要はありませんし、回答への投票も正式な選挙とは無関係になります。

モデレーターが実際どのような活動をしているのか疑問がある方は、遠慮なく質問してください。[チャット](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=ja.stackoverflow.com)でメンションいただければ見に行きますし、メタで質問いただいても大丈夫です。

どうぞよろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 7):

立候補する予定です～。

回答は少なくとも 30 文字必要だと今思い出したのでもうちょっと書くと、モデレーションは暫定モデレーターとして今も楽しんでいるので、もうちょっと続けたいなと思っています。